# clear information in spinner

Tags: android

```
spinner1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Select1);
        spinner2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Select2);
```

I have 2 spinners. Spinner number 2 depends on spinner number 1.

I want a method that I can use it to clear the oldest information that retrieve from database
for spinner 2 each time.

So if I select item in spinner 1 it will retrieve the information for spinner 2, 
depending on the item choose the second time I choose from spinner number one I want to delete the oldest information of spinner 2 and then retrieve the new information.

If it is possible, how so?

Answer (score 0):

i know the answer i search and i find 
 list.clear();
that there is a method call clear you can use it 
hope it help